# SAS proc gplot: Regression line not ligning up with points after adjusting axis range

Tags: plot, sas, regression, axis, proc

I am trying to create a plot using proc glpot. I had to adjust the range of the y-axis (axis2) in order to fit the range of values I was interested in (used order option to accomplis this). The problem is that if I specify the noaxis option for plot2, then then the regression line does not fit properly to my points anymore. If I use the same horizontal and vertical axis (axis1 and axis2 respectively) as the option for plot2 instead, then I end up with another axis on the right side of my plot as shown in the picture below. [image: sample output]

How can I fix it so that I can match my regression line properly with the plot without adding another axis?

```
/* Set the graphics environment */                                                                                                      
    goptions reset=all cback=white border htitle=12pt htext=10pt;   

/* Define the title */                                                                                                                  
title1  "001";                                                                       

/* Define the axis characteristics */                                                                                                   
axis1 label=("Age");                                                                                                              
axis2 label=(angle=90 "Value") minor=(n=4) order= 0 to 1 by .1;                                                                                         

/* Define the symbol characteristics for the scatter plot groups */                                                                             
symbol1 interpol=none value=dot color=R;                                                                                          
symbol2 interpol=none value=dot color=O;
symbol3 interpol=none value=dot color=Y; 
symbol4 interpol=none value=dot color=G; 
symbol5 interpol=none value=dot color=B; 
symbol6 interpol=none value=dot color=P; 
symbol7 interpol=none value=dot color=BL; 

/* Define the symbol characteristics for the regression line */                                                                                 
symbol8 interpol=rlclm90 value=none color=BL W=1;


/* Define the legend options */                                                                                                         
legend1 frame label=none repeat=1                                                                                                    
        value=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7");                                                                                                     

proc gplot data=test;                                                                                                          
   plot value*age=missile / haxis=axis1 
                            vaxis=axis2 
                            legend=legend1
                            vref=.1 
                            vref=.7 
                            lvref=3 
                            cvref=R;                                                                     
    plot2 value*age / haxis=axis1 vaxis=axis2;
    run;                                                                                                                                    
    quit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that if you use the two options vaxis and noaxis together, that it would still apply the axis range but remove the axis label and tick marks from the right side of the plot. Thus the code I changed to get the desired results looked like this:

```
plot2 value*age / vaxis=axis2 noaxis;
```

[image: fixed plot]